# Notice: Undefined index: admin in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped2\index.php Notice: Undefined index: users in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped2\index.php

Tags: php

This is my code.

```
<?php

include("include/dbcon.php");
if($_SESSION['admin']){      //this is where the error starts
    header("location:admin/");
}else if($_SESSION['users']){   //and here also
    header('location:employee/');
}else{
    header:('location:/deped2/');
}
?>
```

Please help me with this code

Comment: chk session, did u start your session or not

Comment: In addition to the current answer which will solve your issue, I would like to suggest using `exit;` after each `header('Location: ...')`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking whether the Session Index is set or not. It would be better if you first start the session then check if the variables are present or not.

Try this and adding `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code might want to continue to execute.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();
}
include("include/dbcon.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){      //this is where the error starts
    header("location:admin/");
    exit;
}else if(isset($_SESSION['users'])){   //and here also
    header('location:employee/');
    exit;
}else{
    header:('location:/deped2/');
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: I would place the include below the conditional. If that fails, then it will throw a headers sent warning and add `exit;` after each header (for a better answer).

Comment: yes you can put include after the condition.